# Deleting a message after sending another one VKBottle

Tags: python, vk

Hello programmers friends!
I have a problem deleting a message after sending another one.

```
new_msg = await message.answer(attachment=photo)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    try:
        new_msg.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['text'])
```

I read the documentation but didn't really understand it.
Can you please help?

Comment: Can you describe your pboblem a little better? Please provide an error message or at least some more insight of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no links and errors to the code. In more detail, I can say that in response to the user's messages, a photo with a download first comes, then after 2 seconds the answer to the question is already sent, and the photo with the download is deleted.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Try adding something to the Except block, maybe something like `print(e.message)`